# How to scroll a java fx chart?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm new to java fx, created a chart and started to fill it with random data, but after some time it just displays last N datapoints, i'd like to have ability to scroll trough chart.

Anyone knows how to do that in java fx?

Comment: have you found the solution? I have a situation like you. If you found that, please share it to me. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

JavaFX contains an scrollpane. Maybe you can use it:

```
<ScrollPane>
   <content>
      <Chart />
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```